# Allow Role to change only Moderation State of Content Type without possibility to edit content fields

Tags: 7, workbench

The system we are building has a role Publisher. 
It's task is to change  Moderation State of a content (news content_type) without having a possibility to edit an actual content.

In short, the user in role Publisher sees all News created by other users and only has permission to change its state.

In short, how do I allow a user in a role to edit only 1 field and block the rest?

Comment: What's your question then? it'd help if you give more info on what your exact question is, and what you have done so far to try and resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I allow a user in a role to edit only 1 field and block the rest?

The standard solution is the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module:

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

It provides you with a role-based UI like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this already but this module doesn't allow to change permission of the TITLE.

Comment: Title is a required property of a node, so it doesn't really make sense to make it permission-based. It'll always need a value. Maybe a combination of some custom code and [Automatic Nodetitles](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) would do the trick

Comment: Yes it doesn't make sense to set permissions on title when you CREATE node but it does when you EDIT. Isn't there any simple solution to having userA creating/editing content and userB publishing only?

Comment: Well I imagine they need access to edit the node to be able to change its moderation state, and that implicitly gives them permission to edit the title. So out of the box, no, you can't do that. You might get some mileage out of the [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module, which converts the title property to a normal field which you can use permissions on, but it might also mean you need to make some changes elsewhere to compensate